# Postfix on Centos - mail slow to send

Tags: centos, postfix

We have a VPS running Postfix 2.3.3 on Centos 5.3, and it seems to take a long time to send an email. 
There is an app running on the server (drupal) that sends off a series of emails on submitting a form, and it seems to be taking a heck of a long time to send them - like maybe 30s to a minute for each one. Even just firing off `mail` from the command line has a similar sluggishness.

If I `tail -f /var/log/maillog` I can see each email go past - there's a big pause before the first and in between each subsequent email.

I have only the vaguest understanding of what I am doing here, so I am not sure what other information I can provide that might prove helpful. As far as I know we just have a fairly bog-standard install of centos,postfix and webmin running.

Any suggestions as to where to look and what to do while I'm looking there would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that your DNS configuration is correct (all the servers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf` are up and answering quickly).  Big delays in sending e-mail usually means DNS problems.

Comment: Everything is a freaking DNS problem! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes i agree with womble. Try to configure dns on local mail server machine and list the local machine as a nameserver on /etc/resolv.conf.It might solve the problem.